Mac Installer format: XAR or DMG?
When inspecting the byte stream of the macOS Big Sur installer SharedSupport.dmg, or any other similar installer like Ventura and so on, I see both a XAR and a DMG structure.
To be more specific, it has:

the XAR signature "78 61 72 21" at the beginning of the file,
and the DMG signature "6B 6F 6C 79" at the end of the file, i.e., there is a 512 byte-trailer that contains the magic signature "koly".

Any DMG package other than a macOS installer does not have such signature at the beginning of the file.
Does that mean a macOS installer isn't actually a DMG file but a XAR file? Why does it have XAR header?

What actual problem or issue are you trying to solve here?

working on tool that extracts and views contents of various archives.

If you have an issue about an app that you are developing you would be better off going to https://stackoverflow.com as questions about development are officially off topic here and you are more likely to get meaningful help there. You could flag your question and ask a mod to migrate your question there, if you like.
